# When to use impl on an empty struct

Tags: rust

I saw the [following code](https://github.com/paul-schaaf/solana-escrow/blob/4a2b92e6a6585f9b73aaad87aaea1cbfd5f0134a/program/src/processor.rs#L17) on the internet:

```
pub struct Processor;

impl Processor {
    pub fn process(

    ) -> i32 {
       // some stuff here
    }
}
```

and used as:

```
let a = Processor::process();
```

What's the advantage of having `struct` here at all? Can the same thing somehow be achieved without it?

Comment: It can come up when you need to implement a trait but doesn't need any state. But in a case like this it's probably just style and preference, the alternative would be just functions in a module.

Comment: It looks like someone has seen too much Java.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of the more common examples you might run into. I'm sure there are others I forgot, but these will hopefully help you when reading rust code in the future.

### Creating structs to hold different implementations of a trait

You may find yourself in a situation where it would be nice to be able to use a custom handler, but want to avoid the overhead of storing a function inside of each struct. An easy alternative is to create a trait for it instead and define types for the sole purpose of having different versions of a trait implemented on them.

This way you can use them like compile-time type modifiers which allow for core functionality to be easily swapped or redefined later without any extra overhead or requiring extra information be stored in a struct.

```rust
trait Smoothing {
    fn smooth(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32;
}

struct LinearStrategy;
impl Smoothing for LinearStrategy {
    fn smooth(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        (a + b) / 2
    }
}

struct GeometricStrategy;
impl Smoothing for GeometricStrategy {
    fn smooth(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        i32::sqrt(a * a + b * b)
    }
}

struct ComplexStruct<T> {
    /* etc. */
    _phantom: PhantomData<T>,
}

// Change how ComplexStruct operates at compile time
impl<T: Smoothing> ComplexStruct<T> {
    pub fn sample(&self, x: i32) -> i32 {
        T::smooth(self.raw_sample(x - 1), self.raw_sample(x + 1))
    }
}
```

The best example I could find of this is probably `Vec`. It may not seem like it at first, but `Vec` has 2 type parameters. In `Vec<T, A = Global>`, the `A` is the allocator used by `Vec`. By default it is set to the global allocator, but in some cases it can be really handy to be able to easily switch it out with something else and still have access to all of the normal functionality of `Vec`.

### Placeholders for FFI

When creating a rust api for a C/other library it may make sense to add types to mirror the C api without containing the same data. Normally that will end up looking like this where a pointer is wrapped with a safe rust alternative and a placeholder lifetime (Since rust does not own this data).

```rust
pub struct Foo<'a> {
    ptr: *mut sys::Foo,
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}
```

However, it may also make sense to use a struct in cases where you need to enforce constructors/destructors are called for a resource. Since Rust calls a struct's `drop` function when it falls out of scope then gets dropped from memory, it is quite easy to enforce these rules. In this case, by having a struct we can enforce some pre-requisite to be filled to gain access to the functions in the struct.

```rust
pub struct FooApi;

impl FooApi {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        unsafe { sys::init_thread_foo(); }
        FooApi
    }

    /// Some call that is only safe if sys::init_thread_foo() has been called
    pub fn do_something(&self) { /* ... */}
}

/// Call FFI function to dispose of this resource once this FooApi is no longer needed
impl Drop for FooApi {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            sys::dispose_thread_foo();
        }
    }
}
```

### Verbosity

Sometimes a struct could probably be replaced with a module. However depending on the developer, they may prefer to use a struct instead in cases where it makes more conceptual sense to think of acting upon an object. Often these cases are reasonably rare and usually indicate that a type previously or will in the future be split into traits and generified. Alternatively it may also be used in cases where there are a couple equivalent, but non-identical alternatives that can be swapped between (Ex: types of CPUs ).

So far those are a couple of the causes that come to mind, but I may come back to add more.